# Is there any way to reliably send data from a UWP[C#] application to commonly used Microsoft applications such as Excel, Word, WordPad & Notepad?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, dde

I have developed a UWP[C#] application that uses the Windows 10 BLE API in order to receive data from a custom BLE device that my company has developed. Now, the requirement of the application is to send data to any active Word file, Excel sheet, Notepad or WordPad document on the local machine.

The data transfer from the UWP App to Excel/Word/Notepad/WordPad has to be automatically done as soon as the UWP app receives any data from the BLE device.

I read about Dynamic Data Exchange Server (DDE Server), however that technology seems very old and I am unable to find any documentation to for it to help me implement a DDE Server in a UWP app.

I am fairly new to Windows App Development and UWP App Development and would appreciate any help provided.

Comment: You could simulate key press events for example to type text in notepad.

Comment: @Emil I tried that already using InputInjector, however the order of data sent to the Injector and its output is not the same always. Data is received using asynchronous events by my app and i cannot send all the data at once to the InputInjector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A UWP application cannot do this directly for security reasons. A UWP application can include a "full trust" component in its package though, and that component can communicate with Office via the standard OLE Automation interfaces.

You can read more about building [UWP and full-trust components here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-extend), and you can learn about [accessing Office via PIAs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/office-primary-interop-assemblies?view=vs-2019).

Comment: is it possible to develop applications using WPF or WinForms that can achieve this? I am aware of the security issues surrounding DDE, however I would be grateful if you could guide me towards an example of an app using some other Windows development framework to achieve this capability.

Comment: If you are using WPF then just call the. Office PIAs directly.